# Is data already sent to the server while connection timeout

Tags: android, http, connection, timeout, server

I built a data process server accepting android and iOS client request. And I set the connection timeout = 5000ms on client. My question is, if the **connection timeout** happens, is the **data is being sent to the server** in the case?

Comment: If a connection timeout happens the connection is not established. So how could there be send something?

Answer (score 0):

connection timeout occurs if initial handshake with server fails within specified time duration (5000ms in this case).

now no further communication is possible within this attempt. i.e. no data is being sent or recieved.